# How can I access GET parameters?

Tags: cakephp

```
public function search() {

$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;



 $this->loadmodel('Usermgmt.User');




if ($this->request -> isGet()) {
        $this->User->set($this->data);
            $keyword=$this->data['Doctors']['search'];

 $cond=array('OR'=>array("User.username LIKE '%$keyword%'","User.email LIKE '%$keyword%'", "User.first_name LIKE '%$keyword%'", "User.last_name LIKE '%$keyword%'", "User.positions LIKE '%$keyword%'"));





 $result = $this->paginate('User',array($cond));

  $this->set('result',$result);



}
```

Here the code for search functionality in cakephp version cakephp-2.4.5 in this when i given request to search `if ($this->request -> isGet()) {` executes and `$keyword` value getting empty.,,here how can i get  **GET parameters** here

Comment: is your $this->data also null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this coding

```
  $this->User->set($this->data);
            $keyword=$this->data['Doctors']['search'];
```

and add this one if u are using get method

```
$keyword = $this->params['url']['keyvalue'];
```

here keyvalue is user parameter name

Answer (score 2):

Thulasi's method will work, but do note that using `$this->params['url']` has been deprecated, in favor of `$this->request->query`. So the new advised way to do it would be:

```
$keyword = $this->request->query['keyword'];
```

Also see [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters) on this topic.